# Finding the uncertainty in angles that need to be changed to radians, when dealing with trigonometry ratios?

Tags: experimental-physics, geometry, error-analysis

I just wanted to ask about how we are supposed to do uncertainties in our experiment since in they y-axis is acceleration/cosx and on the x axis is tanx. Are we supposed to place error bars on both axis? And if so, how are we supposed to find the uncertainty in our angles since we need to change it to radians since we are dealing with trig ratios. Thank you for your time.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Estimating the errors is not as simple as you may think. (For example, see the text Data Analysis for Scientists and Engineers by Meyer for details related to the following discussion.)

You have two functions: $f(a, \theta) = {a \over cos(\theta)}$, and $g(\theta) = tan(\theta)$.  Use radians for $\theta$. In the following discussion, I am addressing the measurements of $a$ and $\theta$. I assume the measurements for $a$ and $\theta$ are independent. For each specific $\theta$, you evaluate $f(a, \theta)$ and $g(\theta)$.    You plot $f(a, \theta)$ as a function of $g(\theta)$, using the estimated means from your data for $f(a, \theta)$ and $g(\theta)$. For each specific $\theta$, the uncertainties in $f(a, \theta)$ and $g(\theta)$ are the estimated standard deviations of the means of each function from your data.  Details follow.

For each specific value of $\theta$, suppose you have k measurements for that specific $\theta$ and $j$ measurements for the $a$ corresponding to that $\theta$.  Based on your data, the estimated mean of a specific $\theta$  is  $\theta_{mean}  = {1 \over k} \sum_{i = 1}^{k}  \theta_i$ where $\theta_i$ is the $i^{th}$ measurement for $\theta$.  The estimated mean for the corresponding $a$ is  $a_{mean}  = {1 \over j} \sum_{i = 1}^{j}  a_i$ where $a_i$ is the $i^{th}$ measurement for $a$.  The estimated mean for $f(a, \theta)$ is ${a_{mean} \over {cos(\theta_{mean})}}$. The estimated mean for $g(\theta)$ is $tan(\theta_{mean})$.

The errors for $f(a, \theta)$ and $g(\theta)$ can be taken as the standard deviations of the means for each function.

For a specific $\theta$, the estimated standard deviation of the mean is $S_{\theta} = \sqrt{{\sum_{i=1}^{k} (\theta_{mean} - \theta_i)^2} \over  {k(k - 1)}}$. The estimated standard deviation of the mean for the corresponding $a$ is $S_{a} = \sqrt{{\sum_{i=1}^{j} (a_{mean} - a_i)^2} \over  {j(j - 1)}}$.  The estimated standard deviation of the mean of $f(a, \theta)$ is $S_f = \sqrt{ ({\partial f \over \partial a})^2S_a^2 +  ({\partial f \over \partial \theta})^2S_{\theta}^2 }$. The estimated standard deviation of the mean of $g(\theta)$ is $S_g = \sqrt{ ({\partial g \over \partial \theta})^2S_{\theta}^2 }$. ${\partial f \over \partial \theta} = asec(\theta)tan(\theta)$. ${\partial f \over \partial a} = {1 \over {cos(\theta)}}$. ${\partial g \over \partial \theta} = (sec(\theta))^2$.

For each specific $\theta$, you report the values as $g_{mean} \pm S_g$ and $f_{mean} \pm S_f$. The following figure is a notional plot showing the errors.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In most experiments plotting two quantities,  one of them is known very much more accurately than the other.  Generally, by convention, we call the precisely known quantity $x$ and plot it horizontally, and the imprecise one $y$ and plot it vertically.

For example, in a typical experiment plotting the temperature of a body as it cools with time, the time is accurately known from a stopwatch, the temperature only to some fraction of a degree.

Studying the distance-time relation of a body, you might measure as best you could  the times at which it crosses sharply-defined distance markers, so the distance is precisely known and the time has errors.
Alternatively you might use a stroboscopic photo which gives sharply-defined times, and distances subject to camera-blur, so it would be the other way round.

I don't know the details of your apparatus, but I suspect that the angles will be accurately measured, with a protractor or ruler, at leisure before the actual experiment, whereas the acceleration will be subject to measurement errors.

There are cases when there are uncertainties on both $x$ and $y$ but they are rare. Do not go this route unless it is forced on you. I know of only two statistics textbooks that handle them, and one gets it wrong.